# in Unix, how to wildcard match files whose name is a number greater than x

Tags: unix, numbers, wildcard

I have a bunch of files named like this:

```
0468.xml
0474.xml
0475.xml
0481.xml
```

I want to match whatever files there are in the directory whose name (without .xml extension) is a number greater than, let say, 0474. In other words, I want to match the last two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
  ls | awk -F. '$1>474'
```

Comment: that's certainly nice and simple. Perhaps you know how to extend the example to handle files with format `0468_2014_10_23.xml`? (how to ignore the timespan when matching?)

Comment: In the example you give, you could simply do `awk -F_ '$1 > x' x=474`  (using the variable makes it easier to pass the value 474 from a shell variable.  The key here is to use `_` instead of `.` as the field separator.)

Comment: so, another question would be, what if I want this but having dirnames as input instead of filenames?

Comment: If you only want to work on directories, change ls to something which only lists directories.  Or, possibly, `ls -F | awk -F. '$1>474 && /\/$/'`

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to solve this. One simple way is to extract the numeric portion that you want to compare and then compare it against your minimum value like below.

```
for file in +([[:digit:]]).xml
do 
    if [ `basename -s .xml $file` -gt 474 ]
    then 
        echo $file; 
    fi; 
done
```

Comment: that's nice and thanks for the help. I actually need something like wildcards, because I want to pass the filtered result as an argument to a script.